# Open links with keyboard keys via jquery

Tags: jquery, navigation, keyboard, hyperlink

I have this script:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: case 38:
        window.open ('link1.html','_self',false);
    case 39: case 40:
        window.open ('link2.html','_self',false);     
}
return;
});
```

It's supposed to navigate between links with keyboard keys, but for some reason only link2 works for any of arrow keys. I guess I have some problem with markup because I'm not very good at javascript. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the "break" statements in your switch statement. Try this:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
switch (e.keyCode) {
case 37: case 38:
    window.open ('link1.html','_self',false);
    break;
case 39: case 40:
    window.open ('link2.html','_self',false);
    break;
}
return;
});
```

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp